# iOS: Write to file while app in background

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I'm trying to log accelerometer data to a txt file on my iPhone. I got it working pretty well, enabled background app mode and also using Location service to keep the CoreMotion running in background.

My problem is the file not being written to while the app is in background.

Is it even possible? I'm using iOS 7 on iPhone 5.

**UPDATE**: Below is my code.

```
- (void)writeToFile:(NSString*)line sensor:(NSString*)sensorType {

    // current date
    NSDate *currentDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"]; //"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    NSString *localDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];

    // storage path and file name
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths lastObject]; //objectAtIndex:0 (iOS 2+)
    NSString *fileDir = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:localDateString];
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@.txt", sensorType, localDateString];
    NSString *filePath = [fileDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    // create folder if not exists
    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fileDir]) {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:fileDir withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
    }
    // create file or append to file
    if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        [line writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:filePath];
        [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];
        [myHandle writeData:[line dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should post the code you are using to write to the file in the background so we can tell you if you are doing it wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the background"? Is the screen locked? In that case full disk encryption might make writing impossible. The user's passcode is not in RAM so only limited access to the disk is possible. Try opening the file for writing before you go into the background, and keep it open the whole time.

Comment: @Will code added for review.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert "background": when pressing home go to another app. no screen is not locked.

Comment: Are you receiving accelerometer events while in the background?  Have you used the debugger to single step through your event handler?  Are you getting error messages attempting to write?  Is your write to disk code even being called?

Comment: @Paulw11 no error message. the write-to-disk works fine while app in foreground. do I have to call write to disk in background update methods? i thought the location update functions keep the app running the same way as it is in foreground.

Comment: Check the background operation modes in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, got it working. I guess all that I needed was dinner to re-energize my brain. What I did was moving my `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` block of code to `AppDelegate.m`, somehow I put it in my `ViewController.m`

Thanks for all the suggestions and comments.

Comment: Common mistake! I wish Xcode would catch these mistakes at compile time, hard to do it though. Design flaw with the delegate pattern I think.